# ¿ Como agregar estilos css para ios?

Tags: javascript, css, ionic3

Estoy trabajando con ionic 3, tengo el siguiente codigo html. El problema es que no se como hacer para que cuando la app se ejecute en ios la etiqueta

obtenga un color puntal como por ejemplo azul.

Actualmente la etique agarra el color azul cuando se ejecuta en android pero no para ios, lo que busco es que el mismo color se muestre tanto para ios como para android.

```html
 <div no-lines *ngIf="isBlockedTemp == false" class="">
     <div class="Inactive">
        <p class="" (click)="Alert()">
            {{ 'Parrafo' }}</p>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta agregandole este css al elemento mediante una clase:

```
--color: primary;
```

Eso si quieres el azul por defecto de la paleta de colores nativa de ionic, en caso contrario, especificar el color de acuerdo a algún formato de colores.

Si esto no funciona intenta:

```
--ion-color: primary;
```

Si esto tampoco funciona intenta:

```
color: tuColor;
```